# Wait until task has completed within a loop before executing next line of code

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using Visual C# 2013 to create a win-forms applications. I have a loop which takes up to a minute to complete due to a large calculation having to be carried out on many rows of data within a table, therefore whilst the user waits I display a 'loading...' form.

On this form I wish to display a count down of the number of rows, so the user can see how many rows of the data there are left to be calculated, however the label with this number on will not update as everything 'freezes' until the loop has finished.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["LoadingForm"];

 int DataRowsRemaining = TotalRowCount;

 for (int i=0; i<=TotalRowCount; i++)
 {
     //CALCULATION CODE

     ((LoadingForm)f).label1.Text = Convert.ToString(DataRowsRemaining--);
 }
```

This code does not allow the label to update during the loop. Using, Application.DoEvents(); after the label does allow it to be updated but this also refreshes every other label on the form which significantly slows down the calculation, therefore I think I need to allow this one line of code to be carried out on a separate thread.

Due to my knowledge being limited on the subject, could anyone advise me whether the multi-threading technique would be the best way to solve this issue, and if so any advice on how I could code this as I have been struggling to understand online examples of multi-threading.

Thanks for your time, Aaron.

Comment: [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way would be

```
await Task.Run(() => {  /* CALCULATION CODE */ });
```

---

```
private async void Calculation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= TotalRowCount; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {  /* CALCULATION CODE */ });

        ((LoadingForm)f).label1.Text = Convert.ToString(DataRowsRemaining--);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I add this into my code I get the error: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing it's return type to 'Task'. Also I probably should have mentioned, the code I wrote is within, private void Calculation() { /* CODE */} which is called from a button click event. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron decorate your method with `async`. Like `private async void  Calculation()`

Comment: @L.B you meant of course `private async Task Calculation()`, void is nonawaitable (event handlers are exception for this rule)

Comment: @L.B My bad, should have actually read above before commenting :) You can't await Calculation since it's void but that wasn't the question.

Comment: When I use 'void' I get the following error: 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

And when I use 'Task' it doesn't complete the tasks and still does not update the count-down number label. Any ideas as to the issue? Also I dont know if it's relavent but I just realised I'm using 'Public' rather than Private, as I have to call if from another form. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

There is an example [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to use `.Invoke()`.  However, L.B's answer is probably much simpler.